# Horizontally scrollable div in table cell: white-space: nowrap + overflow:scroll = not working

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

This works as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:100%">

          <div style="margin:0; padding: 0; width: 100%; overflow: auto; white-space:nowrap;">
            <img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/BwmoBuQeDw9pu/200_s.gif">
            <img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/BwmoBuQeDw9pu/200_s.gif">
            <img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/BwmoBuQeDw9pu/200_s.gif">
            ... many more
          </div>
          <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
          </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(try it here: http://output.jsbin.com/camoku)

The div occupies 100% of the width of the page, and it has a horizontal scrollbar to scroll through its overflowing content.

I would expect this to work exactly the same:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:100%">
    <table style="width:100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="margin:0; padding: 0; width: 100%; overflow: auto; white-space:nowrap;">
            <img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/BwmoBuQeDw9pu/200_s.gif">
            <img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/BwmoBuQeDw9pu/200_s.gif">
            <img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/BwmoBuQeDw9pu/200_s.gif">
            ...
          </div>
          <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this doesn't work. The table expands to host all its contents without scroll; the div has no scrollbar and instead the whole page has.
http://output.jsbin.com/sagedu

Why doesn't this work and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I needed to add

```
table-layout:fixed
```

to the table's style.